# R shiny output table before program finishes execution

Tags: r, shiny

I created a dashboard with 15 data tables in Shiny. Each table draws data from an API and this process takes some time. So I want to output each table to ui at a time such that users can read the first table while the other ones load. But it seems Shiny always holds all output until server function finishes execution. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example (fully working app) with, say, two or three tables with fake data

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. I suspect that you can use `invalidateLater` to read in additional tables, although this may cause Shiny to redraw all tables and interrupt user experience. I don't have anything similar to test with but try it out.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with an app once. What I did was to do the calculations that take much time in another R session. Maybe now there are packages that make it easier, but here is how I solved it:

You can make an `observeEvent` which is triggered by an `actionButton`. In this observer you start another R session (with a system call to `Rscript` for example).

Then the app is still responsive while an R session in the background is doing all the calculations.

To retrieve information from the background process you can use shiny's `reactivePoll` function.

In your case the background R session would do the process each table and write the result into a file once it is done with a table. The `reactivePoll` would watch out for these files. Once such a file appear the `reactivePoll` function can read it and present it as a reactive. The value of this reactive can then be rendered somehow for the user to see.

This way each table is processed 1 by 1, while the app is still responsive and able to show results while the background process is still running.

Here is a app that shows the principle.

#### server

```
library(shiny)

# batch process communicates via file
write("", "tmp.info")

# cheap function to check for results
cheap <- function() scan("tmp.info", what = "")



shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  # start process
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    system2("Rscript", args = c("batch.r", input$num1, input$num2), 
            stdout = "", stderr = "", wait = FALSE)
  })

  # watch file
  watch <- reactivePoll(500, NULL, cheap, cheap)

  # retrieve result from batch process
  result1 <- reactive(if(length(watch()) > 0) watch()[1] else NULL)
  result2 <- reactive(if(length(watch()) > 1) watch()[2] else NULL)

  # show results
  output$add <- renderPrint(result1())
  output$multiply <- renderPrint(result2())

})
```

#### ui

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(sidebarLayout(

  sidebarPanel(
    h2("Add and multiply"),
    numericInput("num1", "Number 1", value = 1),
    numericInput("num2", "Number 2", value = 1),
    helpText("Both numbers are added, and multiplied. Each calculation takes 4 sec."),
    br(),
    actionButton('go', 'Start')
  ),

  mainPanel(
    h4("Result of Addition"),
    verbatimTextOutput("add"),
    h4("Result of Multiplication"),
    verbatimTextOutput("multiply") 
  )

)))
```

#### batch.r

```
# read info
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
args <- as.numeric(args)

# add
res <- args[1] + args[2]
Sys.sleep(4)
write(res, "tmp.info")

# mult
res <- args[1] * args[2]
Sys.sleep(4)
write(res, "tmp.info", append = TRUE)

quit(save = "no")
```

server.r ui.r and batch.r must be in the same directory. A file "tmp.info" is created which is used for communication. The results are directly read from this file and batch.r is started with the input as parameters. You can also use files for all that.